# Add line breaks to Out-File cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the list of computers that has no antivirus but the out file is with computer names in *one single line*, can anyone help?

```
    ForEach ($COMPUTER in (Get-ADComputer -Filter  {OperatingSystem -notLike '*windows xp*' }  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)) 
{if(!(Test-Connection -Cn $computer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet))

{write-host "cannot reach $computer" -f red}


else {

 try
{          
 $AntiVirusProduct = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SecurityCenter2" -Class AntiVirusProduct  -ComputerName $computer -ErrorAction Stop
 }
catch
{
    Write-Warning "[ERROR] invalid namespace [$($computer)] : $_"
    $noantivirus+=$computer
}
$noantivirus  | out-file -Encoding Ascii -append c:\noantivirus.txt}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it

```
$noantivirus = Add-Content c:\noantivirus.txt "`n$computer"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to join them by a *NewLine*:

```
$noantivirus -join [System.Environment]::NewLine | out-file -Encoding Ascii -append c:\noantivirus.txt
```

If this doesn't work, try with  rn:

```
$noantivirus -join "`r`n" | out-file -Encoding Ascii -append c:\noantivirus.txt
```

Comment: No Luck its making triangle, rectangle